# Can Google Ads Data Hub (ADH) be setup in the same GCP project as Google Analytics BigQuery export and 1st party data?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-analytics, google-bigquery, google-ads-data-hub, ads-data-hub

we're trying to understand the pros and cons of setting ADH cloud project as the same project containing our GA360 exports and 1st party data, or creating a new different dedicated project.
This project is used only for these specific purposes (BigQuery analysis).
What is the best practice in this case? any recommendations? past experience?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be any technical issue if you use the same project for ADH, GA BigQuery exports, and your first party data. Only case where having separate projects might make sense are:

- Defining different access rights on the datasets, especially at admin level.
- Having better visibility on costs.

Comment: Yes we eventually used the same project. Thank you